# is mysql $result set when some data is missing?

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

what happens in mysql if there is no data to be inserted. meaning the following code:

```
            $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) 
                                    VALUES ('$var1', '$var2')");
            mysql_close();
```

If $var2 is empty, what happens to the subsequent `if($result)`?
$var1 and $var2 were extracted from an array like so:

```
        $var1= $data->var1;
        $var2= $data->var2;
```

And I happen to know that var2 didn't (or shouldn't return anything, as it wasn't in the original set of data the array retrieved).

Basically my page stops and nothing happens when it is supposed to go into this `if`... but it doesn't. Does that make any sense? I thought that $result exists as long as at least something is going on inside of it? The thing is, the `else` isn't happening either, the whole code just stops in the middle... :(

Comment: If both $var1 and $var2 should be set, you can check for that with `empty()`

Comment: that's what I did I thought... thanks

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>        $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) 
>                                 VALUES ('$var1', '$var2')");
>         mysql_close();
> ```
>
> If $var2 is empty, what happens to the subsequent if($result)?

There is no data "missing". The empty string (`""`) is a perfectly valid field value.

---

> $var1 and $var2 were extracted from an array like so:
>
> ```
>     $var1= $data->var1;
>     $var2= $data->var2;
> ```

You can't get data out of an array like that so, no, they weren't.

---

> The thing is, the else isn't happening either, the whole code just stops in the middle... :(

Turn on error logging. You have an error somewhere that you're not seeing.